# In Jenkins, is there a way to persist npm packages so I don't have to install them in each build?

Tags: jenkins, npm, cloudbees, persist, node-modules

I'm using Jenkins (CloudBees) to build my project, and this runs some scripts in each build to download some node packages using npm.
Yesterday the npm registry server was having troubles and this blocked the build cycle of the project.

In order not to depend on external servers, is there a way to persist my `node_modules` folder in Jenkins so I don't have to download them in every build?

Comment: Use a site npm proxy/cache like sonatype Nexus repository or artifactory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache NPM dependencies on Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870020/cache-npm-dependencies-on-jenkins-pipeline)

Answer (score 4):

You can check the `package.json` file and backup `node_modules` directory.

When you start next build in jenkins, just check package.json file and node_modules backup, if package.json file is not changed, just using previous backup.

```
PKG_SUM=$(md5sum package.json|cut -d\  -f 1)
CACHED_FILE=${PKG_SUM}.tgz
[[ -f ${CACHED_FILE} ]] && tar zxf ${CACHED_FILE}
npm install
[[ -f ${CACHED_FILE} ]] || tar zcf ${CACHED_FILE} node_moduels
```

above is quite simple cache implementation, otherwise you should check the cache file is not damaged.

Comment: I believe `tar zcf ${CACHED_FILE} node_moduels` should be `tar zcf ${CACHED_FILE} node_modules` - just a minor spelling mistake

Answer (score 1):

CloudBees uses a pool of slaves to support your builds, and by nature you can have builds to run on various hosts, so start with a fresh workspace. Anyway, we try to allocate a slave that you already used to avoid download delays - this works for all file stored in workspace.

I don't think this would have prevented issue with npm repository being offline anyway.

Comment: I wonder if npm-cache can help with npm servers being offline: https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-cache.html